# What tense(s) can be used with 'by now'? (+ conditionals)

Tags: tense, conditionals

Which of the following is not correct and why?

- If we had stopped that taxi earlier, **we would be** home by now.
- If we had stopped that taxi earlier, **we would have been** home by now.

My teacher told me the second is incorrect.

In [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/68347/464476) and also [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/129951/162347) they use a similar grammar as the second sentence, yet I'm asking if 'by now' can be used with such tense (relatively check [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/270161/464476)) specially when combined with conditionals. I think 'by now' refers to some period of time from the past until now, so the second sentence could be correct.

Comment: Your teacher is wrong. 'Have been home' can mean 'have arrived at home' in ordinary speech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct, and both have the same effective meaning in the context, but the logic is different.

The logic of the first sentence is: *We **are not home right now** because we didn't stop that taxi earlier*.

The logic of the second sentence is: *We **haven't arrived home yet** because we didn't stop that taxi earlier*.

To "not be home" and to "not have arrived at home yet" are semantically the same thing, so the sentences have the same meaning in the context.